# Convert a numeric variable into categories - median? absolute value?

Tags: categorical-data, likert

Hi: I have a three numeric, continuous variables that are the factor scores that result from a factor analysis of 14 likert items. The analysis suggested three factors. The scores range from about -3 to 3. The scores of the underlying likert items were coded from 0 to 1 (Strongly Agree to Strongly Disagree).

I'd like to convert these into categorial variables of two values: "low" and "high". What is the most appropriate way to do that? To cut them into two even categories, using the median as the breakpoint? Or to use 0 as the absolute value? I can easily achieve both technically, I'm more trying to get my head around the conceptual differences.

The distribution of "low" and "high" are different depending on which strategy I adopt.

Thanks for any insights.
Simon Kiss

Comment: Could you tell us *why* you want to dichotomize the factor scores?  (It's worth contemplating this question because in many cases such an operation--which loses information--is not really needed.)

Comment: Well, the sample size is small (N=376). Unfortunately, the survey got cut off for arbitrary reasons. I'm wondering if reducing it to two categories, instead of including it in the model as a numeric variable allows for greater inferential strength.

Comment: Look at it this way: you are wondering whether performing an operation on your data that *reduces* the amount of information in it could *increase* "inferential strength." If that phrase has anything to do with information, the answer must be no, right? That suggests you have in mind applying some particular, narrow set of inferential procedures that just wouldn't be appropriate for non-categorical data. If that's the case, then it would help to describe them in your question.

Comment: Throwing away information rarely improves the situation. It almost always has the opposite effect. Worse, it can introduce biases.